# Why is this decay of the neutral pion suppressed?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, pions, leptons

I got given a homework problem to check various particle decays, whether they're allowed under the different conversation laws (Baryon, Lepton, charge etc.)

Currently im stuck at the following one:

$$
\pi^0 \rightarrow \mu^+ + e^-
$$

The literature seems to say that the neutral Pion only decays into a pair of Photons or a Electron-Positron pair. So im puzzled why this seems to be impossible.

- The lepton number is fine since its 0 before and $1-1 \rightarrow 0 $ after.
- Baryon as well $1-1 \rightarrow 0 $.
- And electrical charge also $0 \rightarrow 1-1$

The resting energy of the Pion is $134$ MeV and thus enough to create the Muon and Electron mass $105.66 + 0.511$ MeV.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Note that the electron and the muon have different lepton numbers.

Comment: @DavideMorgante Ah thanks

Comment: Withdraw the question, then?